# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^r (r-1)a_i^2\geq\sum_{i,j=1\\i\neq j}^r a_ja_i$?

Tags: inequality, summation

Suppose I have $a_1,\cdots,a_r$ with $a_i\geq 0, \forall i$.

How to prove $$\sum_{i=1}^r (r-1)a_i^2\geq\sum_{i,j=1\\i\neq j}^r a_ja_i$$

I try to use the formula $$\frac{a_i+a_j}{2}\geq \sqrt{a_ia_j}$$

however, I still cannot obtain a clear form. It also seems that we could combine some terms together; however, I cannot fully understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want to show
$\sum_{i=1}^r (r-1)a_i^2
\geq\sum_{i,j=1\\i\neq j}^r a_ja_i
$

Since
$\frac1{r}\sum_{i=1}^r a_i
\le \left(\frac1{r}\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2\right)^{1/2}
$,
$\left(\frac1{r}\sum_{i=1}^r a_i\right)^2
\le \frac1{r}\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2
$,
so that
$\left(\sum_{i=1}^r a_i\right)^2
\le r\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2
$.

Note:
In response to a request
for a proof of this,
see this article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i,j=1\\i\neq j}^r a_ja_i
&=\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1, j \ne i}^r a_ja_i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^r\left(\sum_{j=1}^r a_ja_i-a_i^2\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^r a_ja_i-\sum_{i=1}^ra_i^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ra_i\sum_{j=1}^r a_j-\sum_{i=1}^ra_i^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ra_i\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^ra_i^2\\
&\le r\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^ra_i^2\\
&=(r-1)\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Could you roughly explain why $\frac1{r}\sum_{i=1}^r a_i
\le \left(\frac1{r}\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2\right)^{1/2}
$?

Comment: Arithmetic mean/quadratic mean inequality. I'll add a link to the answer.